# PowerPoint prevents local pictures from being "downloaded"

Tags: powerpoint

I have an image that I use numerous times in a PowerPoint presentation. To reduce the size of the presentation (already in the 10s of MB), I saved the image as a file, then used Insert | Picture and the Link to File dropdown option on the [Insert] button. This seemed to work fine until I re-opened the presentatation and saw "To help protect your privacy, PowerPoint prevented this external picture from being automatically downloaded. To download and display this picture, click Options in the Message Bar, and then click Enable external content."

I am not sure where to find "Options in the Message Bar" in PPT 2007, so I don't know if the effect of clicking "Enable external content" is permanent or only effective for the current presentation. I am also surprised that PPT considers a file on my local hardrive to be an "external picture" that needs to be downloaded.

I could not find a solution to this problem online, so I experimented, found a solution, and am answering my own question. Read on.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with programming.  It would be better suited in [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: a) There's probably no reason to make the image that big in the first place, so if size is an issue, downsample it then insert it into PPT.  b) If you insert the image once then copy it to wherever else it's needed in the presentation, PPT will only keep one copy of the image file; your file won't grow appreciably with each copy.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click the Office button (the Office circle logo in the upper lefthand corner of the window.)
2. At the bottom of the dropdown menu, click "PowerPoint Options".
3. In the list on the left side, click "Trust Center", then "Trust Center Options".
4. In the list on the left side, click "Trusted Locations", then "Add new location...".
5. In the "Microsoft Office Trusted Location" dialog, enter the folder containing the file you want to be automatically "downloaded". I entered "D:\Training" even though the file is in "D:\Training\FirstLevelMaint\Working\Graphics".
6. If you entered a parent folder, as I did, check the "Subfolders of this location are also trusted" box.
7. Click "OK" 3 times to get out of the dialog windows.
8. Close the presentation and reopen it. The pictures should appear. They did for me.